# Touch input "buttons" in SurfaceView

Tags: android

I'm doing a game and I have a class that I call `GameLoop` and it extends `SurfaceView` and implements `Runnable`. I need some options for the player to choose from. I also have the class `MainActivity` that extends `Activity` and implements `OnTouchListener`I just wonder if the best approach is to place a text or image on the screen and then check if the touch input coordinates is within the area of the text or image? Or is there a better approach for this? I guess common buttons isn't available togehter with `SurfaceView`?

Answer (score 0):

`SurfaceView` extends `View` - you can just have a `RelativeLayout` as your parent and float buttons (with their own `onClickListeners`) on top of it like any other `View`. Try it, it works.

For example:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <SurfaceView />
    <LinearLayout>
      <Button1 />
      <Button2 />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: OK, but I guess there will be problems, because I extends Activity.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem...You don't mention this in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I have a class That I call GameLoop and that extends SurfaceView and also implements Runnable. Then I have the MainActivity that extends the Activity and implements OnTouchListener